# Please advice a free video player for my site

Tags: html, video

Waht non-commercial (free) good video player can yous suggest in order to put on my webpage? I am doing it first time and have no idea what is now being widely used.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Is http://videojs.com/ video player good? (format support, reliability, fast download, comparability ???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flowplayer: http://flowplayer.org/

It's the best player I've ever seen. Easy to use, customize and integrate with other solutions like ajax or lightboxes.

Plus, it's HTML5 compatible an has a variety of plugins and vast documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube embedded?

Or there are others such as flowplayer and jwplayer

Or use html5's `<video>`

Answer (score 1):

I think this resource can help you: [21 Free Video Players For Your Website and Blogs](http://www.instantshift.com/2010/05/14/21-free-video-players-for-your-website-and-blogs/).
Anyway, if you want to use HTML5 stuff, you can use the new `video` tag.

Edit: I used videojs and it worked well for me.